# Como hacer un CheckBox con ThreeState que cambie al tercer estado a partir de un CheckListBox en Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un CheckBox que me permite seleccionar o deseleccionar todos los elementos de un CheckListBox. Lo que quiero es que me muestre el tercer estado cuando no estén seleccionados o deseleccionados todos los elementos del CheckListBox.

Es decir que lo que me encuentro es con estas situaciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que quiero es que cuando no esten seleccionados o deseleccionados todos los elementos del CheckListox se muestre así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que he intentado hacer para que se cumpla esas condiciones es el siguiente:

```
private void ckbSeleccionarSoftware_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ckbSeleccionarSoftware.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < clbSoftware.Items.Count; i++)
            clbSoftware.SetItemChecked(i, true);
    }

    else if (ckbSeleccionarSoftware.CheckState == CheckState.Unchecked)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < clbSoftware.Items.Count; i++)
            clbSoftware.SetItemChecked(i, false);
    }
    
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < clbSoftware.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (clbSoftware.GetItemChecked(i) == true && clbSoftware.GetItemChecked(i+1) == false)
            {
                ckbSeleccionarSoftware.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate;
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

He usado el evento CheckedStateChange para que me muestre los diferentes estados según se encuentre el CheckListBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que cuando cambia el estado de un item en el *CheckListBox* ha de cambiar el *CheckBox* y viceversa, creamos una variable para conocer y no interferir en la operación de cambio ya que al modificar el estado estamos disparando eventos de cambio de estado.

```
bool OnUpdating = false;
```

Creamos un método para la actualización del *CheckListBox* observa que activamos OnUpdating al inicio para saber que estamos operando y lo desactivamos al final:

```
void update_clbSoftware()
{
    OnUpdating = true;
    // Miramos el valor que tiene el CheckBox
    bool checkValue = (ckbSeleccionarSoftware.CheckState == CheckState.Checked);
    // Y lo trasladamos a los elementos del CheckListBox  
    for (int i = 0; i < clbSoftware.Items.Count; i++)
        clbSoftware.SetItemChecked(i, checkValue);

    OnUpdating = false;
}
```

Por otro lado nos creamos también un método para la actualización del *CheckBox*:

```
void update_ckbSeleccionarSoftware()
{
    OnUpdating = true;
    // Obtenemos número de elementos seleccionados en el CheckListBox
    int itemsSelectedCount = clbSoftware.CheckedIndices.Count;
    // Si hay algún elemento seleccionado y no son todos entonces
    // el caso es Indeterminate.
    if (itemsSelectedCount > 0 && itemsSelectedCount != clbSoftware.Items.Count)
    {
       ckbSeleccionarSoftware.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate;
    }
    else
        // Llegados a este punto, si no es un caso intermedio entonces o son todos
        // checked o unchecked. Por eso comparamos el primer elemento de la lista
        // y si está marcado entonces será Checked, de otro modo Unchecked.
        ckbSeleccionarSoftware.CheckState = (clbSoftware.GetItemChecked(0)) ? CheckState.Checked : CheckState.Unchecked;

    OnUpdating = false;
}
```

Bueno, ya sólo nos resta implementar los eventos, para el caso del ChekBox sería el siguiente:

```
private void ckbSeleccionarSoftware_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!OnUpdating) update_clbSoftware();
}
```

Y para el CheckListBox sería este otro:

```
private void clbSoftware_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    // Deshabilitamos evento
    clbSoftware.ItemCheck -= clbSoftware_ItemCheck;
    // Nos aseguramos que el nuevo valor se establece en esta rutina
    clbSoftware.SetItemCheckState(e.Index, e.NewValue);
    // Habilitamos evento
    clbSoftware.ItemCheck += clbSoftware_ItemCheck;

    if (!OnUpdating) update_ckbSeleccionarSoftware();
}
```

Observa que hemos deshabilitado/habilitado momentáneamente la subscripción al evento para poder asignar el nuevo valor y asegurarnos en este mismo método del cambio de estado del mismo, sin que generemos eventos adicionales.

Comment: Buenas @Antonio S.F. he probado el código tal y como has puesto en la respuesta pero nada sigue sin cambiar al tercer estado.

Comment: Te he modificado la respuesta por completo. Échale un vistazo, yo la he probado y funciona. En mi primera respuesta no me había dado cuenta que se estaba modificando el estado del CheckBox desde el propio evento CheckStateChanged del CheckBox. Hay que lidiar entre el CheckListBox y el CheckBox en conjunción ya que los estados de uno dependen del otro y viceversa.

Comment: Efectivamente así funciona a la perfección. Muchas gracias por la explicación ha sido muy  didáctica. @Antonio S.F.